# Predict gamlss one-inflated beta model

Tags: r, predictive-models, beta-regression, gamlss, one-inflation

How do you obtain predicted probabilities for the one-inflated component (nu model) of a one-inflated beta regression in `gamlss`?

I have built the following model

```r
zib <- gamlss(prop.abun.max ~ season + time + temp + 
                 last.rain.bom + rain + wind + cloud + 
                 re(random = ~1|site), 
                 sigma.formula = ~1, 
                nu.formula = ~ season + time + temp + 
                last.rain.bom + rain + wind + cloud + 
                re(random = ~1|site), 
                family = BEINF1, 
                data = na.omit(subset2))
```

I obtain predicted probabilities for the beta distribution component of my model (the mu model) using

```r
  head(predict(zib, what = "mu", type = "response"))
[1] 0.7519171 0.7366541 0.7605794 0.6904190 0.7578658 0.7280828
```

This produces values in the range 0-1 which I assume are predicted probabilities.

However, similar code that references the one-inflated component of my model (the nu model) obtains values that are on the range 0.3-4.1. These values are clearly not predicted probabilities as many values are greater than 1.

```r
  head(predict(zib, what = "nu", type = "response"), n = 10)
 [1] 0.6079466 0.9698540 0.7028005 0.6680394 0.6896672 0.6375064 0.6461947 0.6620159 1.2440965 0.7722830
```

The best post I have found on this is [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Predict-probabilities-with-gamlss-R-package-BEINF-family). This posts asks a similar question for a zero- and one-inflated beta model in `gamlss`. However, this answer is not applicable to a one-inflated beta model only (i.e without the zero-inflation) and the reference text suggested by the post no longer seems to be available.

Any advice/assistance to obtain the correct predicted probabilities for the one-inflated component (nu model) of a one-inflated beta regression in `gamlss` would be very much appreciated?

Comment: Are you sure they aren't on the logit scale?

Comment: $\nu$ is parametrized as $\nu = p_1/(1 - p_1)$, the odds of a $1$. Fitting is done on the log-odds (logit) scale. So in order to calculate $p_1$, you have to take $\nu/(1 + \nu)$, as explained in the post you linked to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The predicted probabilities that Y=1 are given by

p1 = nu/(1+nu)

So just predict nu and then transformation nu to p1.